# Customizing jQuery UI Autcomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to make a few customizations to jQuery UI Autcomplete:

1) If there are no results found it should output "no results found" in the list.

2) Is it possible to highlight/bold the letters in the results as they are being typed? For example if I type "ball" and I have "football" in my results it needs to output as foot **ball**

3) Is it possible for the results that appear at the top to match the beginning of the string. For example suppose I have 3 entries in my database:

- Astrologer
- Space Station
- Star

I start typing "st" - this will bring up those 3 entries in that order. But I want "Star" to be the first result.

The MySQL query being used at the moment to generate the results is:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM customer WHERE name LIKE '%".$_GET['term']."%' ORDER BY name");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can simply echo 'No results found' inside the script that returns the list if num rows from your mysql_query is 0.
2. This was possible in the [original Autocomplete](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/) plugin but I can't see it anywhere in the JQuery UI documentation.
3. You may have to run two separate mysql queries - the first one looking for LIKE '".$_GET['term']."%' and the second one as you have it, but excluding the results you've already got from the first query.